# Best way to poll multicast messages?

Tags: java, udp, multicast, datagram

I'm trying to write a routine that will poll incoming UDP multicast messages sent to multiple ports on a single multicast group, across all network interfaces.

I can do this using `DatagramSocket`, but I can't find a way to check if data is available, or to make it non-blocking. All I can do is set a timeout, call `receive` and wait for an exception if there's nothing there.

Usually, there is at most one port and one network interface with data, so with 4 ports and 4 network interfaces and a timeout of 50ms, it takes ~800ms to read.

If I look at equivalent C# code, there is a [`Socket.Available`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.sockets.socket.available?view=netcore-3.1) property which returns the amount of data ready to be read. If it's zero, I can skip the socket (/port/network interface) and reading is much faster.

Is there a way to do something similar in Java?

Comment: I don't know java, but normally I'd use something that ended up calling [`select`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Select_(Unix)) (or one of its modern equivalents) on all sockets at once.  that would come back saying these sockets are available for reading.  there seem to be similar APIs available in Java, but failing that you could always spawn a thread for socket

Comment: Yes, I eventually figured out the answer, and it's to use the equivalent of `select` - create a `DatagramChannel` for each port and register it with a `Selector`. Code works great now!